# Office 365, outlook add-in icon does not update

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin

Developing an office 365, outlook add-in. Changed the add-in icon (Basically just replaced the old icons with new one. Icons have the same name.). Icon comes up fine on OWA but on Outlook 2016 add-in still, shows the old icon.

Troubleshooting steps till now :

- Uninstall reinstall add-in => no effect.
- Uninstall add-in, restart Outlook 2016, reinstall add-in => no effect.
- Reset customizations from 'Customize Ribbon' option inside 'Outlook Options' => no effect.
- Restarted server => no effect

validate-office-addin shows 'manifest.xml' as valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it by simply renaming the icon files and updating the manifest files accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

You need to delete the local cache. Delete the contents of %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\

Comment: Thanks, @Rick. Well, I resolved it by simply renaming the files and updating the manifest files accordingly.

Comment: @RickKirkham Once I was desperate to find this information when changed the icons of the app. To be honest end up remaining the icons, well ... shortcuts ;) Thanks for tip.