# office add-in commands button icon images not showing up

Tags: office-addins

I have created a Office web addin for Excel, which creates a custom tab with Addin command buttons, the icons which appear on the custom tab always show up with a blue video camera kind of image like shown below, even though the icon I specified in manifest xml file exists with a different image like the one shown underneath the first image

I verified the image url specified in the manifest xml file in the browser and it shows the right image

Please help, 
Thanks in advance
Ira

Wrong image on icons
[image: Image1]

Correct image which should come up

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you share your manifest?  Do the icon URLs point to http or https?  (It should be https)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I changed the URLs to https and everything worked on my home computer, will try the same at work tomorrow, now the images are also showing up. Thanks very much

Comment: Hello Michael, I have the same problem, but my icon URLs are pointing to https.
The Add-In and the icons are hosted on Azure and the same icon url did work before, but since the icon has changed it's not displayed anymore. Though it is still working in Excel Online. Icon URL: https://tecit-sto-office.azurewebsites.net/Images/Icon_STO_32x32.png Add-In: https://appsource.microsoft.com/product/office/wa104381026

Comment: I also tried to rename the icons and delete the contents of local cache like suggested in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332761/office-365-outlook-add-in-icon-does-not-update
Unfortunately this didn't have any effect.

Comment: It seems like this is only happening with icons hosted on Azure. Icons on our own webserver are working as expected.

Comment: for me the root cause was a nginx setting having `Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";` this Cache-Control header set to the incoming requests which caused the icon not to show on Outlook2016

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I am getting the same issue, what is the correct Cache-Control value to solve this problem?

Comment: @Bill Please check my comment above, I have used `Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";`

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone, Office add-ins do not appear to work with image resources located on localhost. You have to use a publicly available address for the images. Here is my config:

- A Vue CLI + Office.js project
- Office 2019 (standard desktop)
- Using `npm run serve` with `https://localhost:8080` setting
- manifest file is syntactically correct as per docs

As long as my images reside on `localhost`, Word refuses to load them and instead shows the blue fallback icons. As soon as I move them to a public host and change their URL in the manifest, the icon appears correctly.

Also note that `validate` also fails for my manifest file when using `localhost` url for the icon. Looks like this script invokes an online service that tries to fetch icon URL (and obviously can't find the locally hosted content).

## Update

`~remoteAppUrl` must be replaced with the actual URL of the add-in. Appears to work correctly for both local and Internet-based URLs in Word 2019.