# How to stop Starlette from setting "Cache-Control: no-cache"?

Tags: cache-control, starlette

I have a uvicorn / starlette app set up with:

```py
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.routing import Route
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from starlette.routing import Mount

DIST_DIR = "dist"

routes = [
    Mount('/', app=StaticFiles(directory=DIST_DIR), name="static"),
]

middleware = [
    Middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['*'], allow_methods=['*'], allow_headers=['*'])
]

app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=routes, middleware=middleware)
```

All files served from starlette have `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache` headers set.

As I use tihs app to serve an Office add-in, this is causing problems because the icon is not displayed in the desktop version of the app (see the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086236/office-add-in-commands-button-icon-images-not-showing-up) for context).

**How can I configure starlette to not send a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header?**

Comment: You could likely use a middleware and have those response headers removed/modified. You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76268510/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71883126/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) helpful.