# Message Compose Outlook add-in is not activated in Outlook 2016 desktop

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I developed an add-in with a `MessageComposeCommandSurface` extension point.

It appears, is activated and works on `outlook.office.com` but with windows desktop client, Outlook 2016 (version 16.0.8625.2121), the button appears in compose mode but stays gray and it is not clickable.

[image: screenshot of mail compose]

I tested the `command-demo-addin` mentioned in Microsoft Docs and published on [Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo) with the same result. Similarly, as shown on screenshot, it is impossible to click and launch the add-in which seems unactivated.

Comment: Posting your manifest would help. Also, clarify what are you composing (message, meeting, etc.)? Nobody will look up some "command-demo-addin" published by Jason; you just need to provide the link.

Comment: Thanks @SlavaIvanov . Jason is part of the Microsoft developer team and most of the answers come from him ! The command-addin-demo is part of the reference files given in microsoft documentation. Here you will find the  [manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo). It seems a bit anoying that resources given don't work... About your first point, it is about composing a message. Check the ExtensionPoint i mentioned.

Comment: Hi @Sybic2001, buttons could be grayed out if the message is DRM enabled, SMIME signed or encrypted. Support for SMIME signed messages in Outlook 2016 C2R versions is expected in a future version.
Would you be able to tell us the build number and send a screenshot of what you see in the desktop client as well as the manifest you're using?

Comment: Thanks for introduction of Jason, nice to know, but just posting simple link to the referenced resource will simplify the things. Anyways, I took the manifest from the resource and it works perfectly without any changes on Outlook 2016 in compose and explorer view. At this point you should consider my request of posting your manifest.

Comment: Thanks. The manifest of the command-demo-addin is [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/blob/master/command-demo-manifest.xml). The version of Outlook 2016 : `Microsoft Outlook MSO 16.0.8625.2121 64 bits`. It is linked to a 365 account.

Comment: Once again, your manifest required, not one from github. I believe you've made some changes to it before publishing. I'd like to see your changes. You should change at least path for images, are you? Or you loaded images from github as well? Did you put then in appropriate folder: "Assets/Images/"; did you load all sizes? Do you run your app on localhost port "8443", like it's in example manifest? Too many questions, as you are not cooperating to post your modified version of manifest. Bottom line: if you made ANY changes to manifest, post this version; if you used it as is, check images.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov, I took the whole add-in folder. Put it on azure on an https cluster. And changed the path of all files and assets with my url in the manifest. So it is exactly the same manifest replacing all occurences of localhost:8443 with my https folder url. All the other options of the addin work (read mode). It is just the message compose mode that doesn't get activated.

Comment: Perfect. This is what you should try: 1. Verify every image path, when you "copy&paste" your URL (watch for missing slash). 2. Check every image size and it is accessible (grab URL of an image, paste it into browser, observe image, right click, check size). 3. Change images names to something else, replace to new name in manifest and load new manifest into Outlook. And/Or [clear Outlook cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332761/office-365-outlook-add-in-icon-does-not-update)

Answer (score 2):

The *COMPOSE* buttons are disabled in the following instances:

1) The Item is in a public folder.

2) The Item is in Junk, Outbox (not drafts), or Sync Issues.

3)  The item is "secure". DRM, or S-MIME encrypted. (older versions of Outlook also do not support S-MIME signed)

4) Outlook is offline.

In the situation where Read Mode add-ins are working, but Compose does NOT it is almost always #3. Usually the user will have on the option to always DRM / S-MIME their outgoing messages.

Update with image of security settings:

[image]

If Com Add-ins load a Custom Form this can also affect add-ins:

Checking Com Add-ins:

Note that outlook actually ships with some add-ins and a lot of com-addins work fine with Web Add-ins. It's only when Com Add-ins override the default new mail form (or other forms) that they can interfere with Web Add-ins.

Some COM add-ins will NOT use Custom Form, but will access the parent folder (item.Parent) and there is currently a bug that disable's Web Add-ins when a COM Add-in or VBA script does this.

File->Options->Add-Ins-> "Go" (next to manage add-ins)

[image: Com Add-ins]

Comment: Ok thnaks I checked : No public folder, no Junk Outbox or Sync Issues, Outlook is online. For n°3, I went to `option >  more options > security parameters`  when composing a new message and everything is unchecked... And again, the addin is working well on the web...

Comment: I'm not familiar with those options settings that you refer to? E-mail Security settings should be under File->Options->Trust Center Settings->Email Security Then make sure those settings are set off. Additionally, when your compose form is open, under Options->Permissions, nothing should be set. I've updated the answer with screenshots of those two places in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, indeed there was a checkbox selected, the same shown on your screenshot. I disabled it, restarted outlook, but still the same issue... It remains grey and the addin cannot be launched.

Comment: It looks like you're doing everything right but we are unable to reproduce this issue.  Do you have any COM add-ins or custom forms installed? Could you try a different machine and see if the issue still persists?

Comment: Indeed, but it seems I'm not alone in that situation. Mvpkenlin mentioned it in the comments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial)

Comment: One additional thing to try. When you *reply* to a message so that the reply is "inline" to the explorer (the main desktop Outlook) window, INSTEAD of a "pop-out" inspector window, are those buttons enabled or disabled? (what happens when you click on them). If replies on your machine "pop out" in a new window, it is a setting you can change in File->Options->Mail->Replies and Forwards->Open Replies and Forwards In New window (should be unchecked)

Comment: Indeed, when replying, it finally gets activated ! As well as when you save it as draft and reopen it. But still remains unactivated when composing from scratch.

Comment: When you save as a draft and reopen it. Does Reopen mean you are popping it out in a new window? or inline in the reading pane in the main outlook window? Also when you reply, and pop it out in a new window does it work? (or does it only work when it is in the main outlook window in the reading pane?

Comment: Also when it is replying and it gets activated. Does the add-in open correctly when you click the button? Or do you get an error message?

Comment: Can you double check that you have NO custom forms and NO Com-Add-ins that use custom forms?

Comment: I don't know what are custom forms and "Com-Add ins" : can you be a little more specific so I can check ?

Comment: Concerning replies and  drafts : it is activated in both cases : by popoing out a new window, and also inline.

Comment: Sorry I just want to get some clarification to be sure. (activated is a loaded term) When you go to click on those buttons in the Inline Reply, does the task pane add-in actually open? Can you use it? Unfortunately, we still are unable to repro this in house, so the more details we get around this bug will help us repro it. I also added instructions to check your com add-ins above.

Comment: Recently we've found that certain COM Add-ins can cause this issue. (New Items not allowing Add-ins, but Replies, and Saved Drafts will work). If the COM Add-in is listening to the New Inspector event, and moving the item to the Outbox (or any other disallowed folder, then the add-ins will be disabled and grey'ed out) The COM Add-in will have to be removed, or readjusted.

Comment: (As an addendum to the above comment, it's if a COM-Add access the parent folder (not just move it)) that can cause the issue. The workaround still remains the same (remove the COM add-in), but we are working on fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an antivirus instaled like avast, try to disable the addin of this and then try to open your compose mail window.